# Can mobs see me through glass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to know if mobs can see me through glass and therefore pile up in front of my window even if I stand 2 square away?

I currently have a rather small stone house with a wooden door and no windows. I would like to add windows to make it look nice but I don't want to attract mobs.

Comment: I had the same concerns when I built my first house. I added many windows, but only at the second floor, just in case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've noticed that ghasts won't shoot fireballs if you are COMPLETELY encased in glass, but if there is one hole, they will blast all your glass to smithereens.

Also, spiders and other mobs can see you without glass--I don't think glass makes a difference.  If you are inside they will go above you and wait you out--when you walk outside they will follow you and fall on you from above.

They are so persistant about this that I usually build a trap--a hole in the roof with a little room lined with cactus and a glass floor.  When I hear a bad critter at night I walk under the glass floor of the little room.  They follow me and jump into the room (pit--which is over my head).  I walk away so that they rub up against a cactus until they die.

It's a manual process but 100% safe.

btw, creepers will fall down there but probably won't die, they like to hide between the cacti and not move until they can actually get to you--but at least they are out of the way.

Comment: This is awesome !

Comment: -1. This is wrong (or outdated). While your first statements are true, you can't extend them to all mobs. And as a matter of fact, zombies and spiders are an exception to the general rule (which is: mobs can't see through glass).

Comment: @Aeronth If you wrote an answer to that effect (spiders and zombies can see through transparent blocks, other mobs can't), I would upvote it.

Answer (score 13):

Let's put some references here.

> Mobs (excluding Zombies, Spiders and Slimes) cannot draw line of sight through glass.

And I think this one in particular is **more than relevant** :

> Endermen can't see the player through transparent blocks such as glass/glass panes.

Feel free to stare at them from your house now. It feels quite good.

**Reminder**: Hostile mobs will follow you even if something blocks their line of sight, as long as you're not out of range.

**Links**:

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman

Answer (score 5):

They can see you and will come after you. But as long as you stay inside, there is no problem.

Creepers won't explode and skeletons won't shoot you. But they will follow you around the house (on the outside, of course).

Comment: The only problem you might have is getting out :')

Comment: hey, you got a sword for that :p
or you can wait till it's daylight and they burn up

Comment: spiders won't burn!

Comment: Neither do creepers.

Comment: spidres are passive during the day and creepers are slow enough to run away from.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true--If a creeper is standing outside your door or a wall and you move up against the same door/wall (but on the other side)... ssssssssssss.

Comment: yeah, well, that's the game

Comment: @Sir Spiders are only passive if they didn't chase you during night. Therefore if you moved inside the area of detection of a spider during night he will keep chasing you.

Comment: @Bill that's why your walls are 2 thick ;)
Basically dig yourself out :') Or you could get on the roof and bow-and-arrow-snipe them :P

Comment: @Bill this is no longer true. Now you can be literally face-to-face with a creeper through a door, and it'll only look at you in dismay. You can even attack it through the door and it won't explode (so long as you're pressed flat against the door, so it doesn't open when you attack).

Answer (score 1):

I think creepers can see through doors and glass, because when I look through the door or window, they're just sitting there looking at you.

Answer (score 0):

I think they see you. I open my door, walk out about half a block, they come to the door. I go back where there is a window, they just stare...  [With the creeper, it just looks so sad...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX2de.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

They can see through doors. A skeleton was shooting arrows at me through the doors. But yes mobs do see through glass but they don't attack you.