# Can mobs see me through lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a rail track go into the lava in the Nether, and I thought it'd be pretty cool if I used glass when building around lava, and non-transparent blocks when building in the air.

But can a Ghast see me through lava and shoot a fireball? I really don't want my track getting messed up. I'm pretty sure mobs can see through glass (it's glass, after all), but I can't see through lava, so I figure they can't.

Comment: You could add everything to a team and that way they won't target you. I can add an answer if you want me to explain how to do this: As an alternative.

Comment: Actually to answer your Question ill add an answer.

Comment: I also added a second option to exchange the glass with barriers. But to answer your Question yes they do target you through it.

Comment: An easy way to manage this might simply be to put a layer of blocks behind the lava. I.e. `stone | lava | glass`

Comment: Note that mobs can actually see you through *walls*, not just glass. [They will not attack through glass (or any other kind of walls) anyway, though.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21665/can-mobs-see-me-through-glass)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this and assumed that they do see you and target you through lava.

[image: Plan]

My chosen mob was the skeleton and it successfully shot me through the lava. The arrows caught fire and hit me. I have two solutions:

**Method One**

Paste this command into chat:

```
/scoreboard teams add train
```

And then paste this command into chat:

```
/give @p minecraft:repeating_command_block
```

Place the block and paste the following command inside (by right clicking it):

```
/scoreboard teams join train @e
```

Set the command block as always active. The command block should then look like this:

[image: Heya]

**Method Two**

Exchange the glass for barriers. Barriers are invincible. To get them paste the following command in chat:

```
/give @p minecraft:barrier
```